# $REQUEST_METHOD is not working in xcart

Tags: x-cart, register-globals

I am working on xCart website. I am asked to fix the issue with forgot password form. After submitting the form there is one logic to check the form is submitted with POST method.

```
if ($REQUEST_METHOD == 'POST'
    && $action == 'recover_password'
    && !empty($username)) 
{

   //Written code to send email for forgot password

}
```

But this condition is not always satisfied so that used could not get new password.

It's giving GET when i displayed $REQUEST_METHOD. I think, It's default one. But when i check with the form there is a method POST.

Do i need to enable/disable register global by going through php.ini ?

Or else anything needs to be done in xCart configuration to make it works fine ?

Please help me in this, Your help will be highly appreciated !

Regards,
Thiru !

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to enable/disable register global by going through php.ini ?

Register_globals should be disabled, see system requirements for X-Cart v4.5.5 and later :
http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Server_Requirements_%28X-Cart_4.5%29#PHP_configuration

To answer the other questions, some more info is required, in particular, what x-cart version you use.

I recommend that you send your question  ( and specify the version + store URL) to support@x-cart.com.